# start intent from adb shell with complex parameters

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I can start an intent from adb shell using following command

```
adb shell "am start -W -a SOME_ACTION \
        -e SOME_EXTRA_KEY SOME_EXTRA_VALUE"
```

However, I can only pass extra as a string value. Is it possible to pass complex data type there, I'd like to pass a Map< String, String> for SOME_EXTRA_VALUE but I'm not sure if that's possible. Can I achieve this? Thanks.

Edit: this is for testing purpose and I want to write script to send intents to my app with different parameters. If there is a tool that can do this, I'd like to know as well.

Comment: No its not, but you could pass in pieces of extras that are translated into a map object when it is received by your Activity/Receiver.